# Django: IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory while Reading JSON file path using python

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting No such file or directory error , while trying to read JSON file from my local django app.

**Please Note** i tried most of the method mentioned on Stackoverflow. so think before saying duplicate...

here is my code,

Try 1:

```
json_data = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL, "utils/config/my_json")
data = open(json_data,'r')
```

Try 2:

```
json_data = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "utils/config/my_json")
data = open(json_data,'r')
```

Try 3:

```
json_data = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL, "utils/config/my_json")
with open(json_data,'r') as file:
    print file
```

I am getting this error,

```
IOError at /my_url/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/utils/config/my_json'
```

file url after performing `os.path.join()` is `'/static/'`

where is the issue in my code? how to read JSON in my case?

Comment: can you show “BASE_DIR”，“STATIC_URL” full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
json_data = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', "utils/config/my_json")
data = open(json_data,'r')
```

Kindly make a folder named `static` in the BASE_DIR directory.
I guess since the STATIC_URL starts with `/` it searches in the root directory

Comment: this method work. even i tired, 'static/utils/..' but i want to know will it work on server? because when it is deployed static will become staticfiles. will it works on both cases?

Comment: Yeah it will work. Reading a file from disk has nothing to do with its URL. But configure it correctly. This is how I do it. `STATIC_URL = '/static/';
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
);
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

Answer (score 0):

You're using STATIC_URL where you should be using STATIC_ROOT. Reading a file from disk has nothing to do with its URL.

Note first that the static dir probably already has BASE_DIR prepended. Also note, this is not really a static file at all and probably should just be in your code directory instead.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT having 'staticfiles' instead 'static' so, i think it might work on server not in my local wsgi server. am i right?